# He had just received word

Tags: word-meaning, sentence-meaning

> “He had just **received word** that Uber was experiencing difficulties tracking the shooter’s getaway car.”
>
> <sup>Excerpt From: Dan Brown. “Origin: (Robert Langdon Book 5).”</sup>

I am wondering why there is no article before *"word"*. My understanding of the sentence is

> He had just got **a message/notification** from Uber.

so *"receive a word"* would mean *"receive a short message"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Word" can be used as a mass noun meaning news or information, and in that case there would be no preceding article, e.g. word came from London that the King was dead.

> 2.1 mass noun Communication; news. ‘I was afraid to leave Edinburgh in case there was word from the War Office’

[Word (Oxford Dictionaries)](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/word)